# Reading empty feature table with FME / Python?

Tags: python, esri-geodatabase, mapinfo, fme-form

I would like to convert a feature table Geodatabase (empty) to MapInfo, but my feature table is empty.

I would like to write the schema of feature table in MapInfo file.

Is it possible to **force** the writer MapInfo ?